# Sharing port 80 between Zimbra and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, zimbra

I'm using `zimbra 6 (6.0.8_GA_2661.RHEL5_20100820051652 CentOS5)` on CentOS 5 server

Zimbra is working fine.

Now I want to host some files on Apache.

I'm referring [to this document on how to run Apache and Zimbra webmail on the same host.](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZimbraApache#Running_apache_and_zimbra_webmail_on_the_same_host)

But when I run below command gives an error

```
zmprov ms zimbra.mydomain.com zimbraMailPort 81
```

Error:

> ERROR: account.NO_SUCH_SERVER (no such server: zimbra.mydomain.com)

Comment: What is the output of `nmap localhost -p80,81` to check if the Apache web server port (80) and the zimbra port (81) are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's pretty clear from the error, that the command is not able to resolve zimbra.mydomain.com.

To check the same, try this command at your terminal:

```
# host zimbra.mydomain.com
```

I believe that it shouldn't work.

To fix the same, open your /etc/hosts file with vi command like this

```
# vi /etc/hosts
```

and create a entry like this

```
ip_address_zimbra  zimbra.mydomain.com
```

Save file and quit and try the command again.

Comment: i hv tried, domain resolving to ip address. zimbra.mydomain.com has address xx.xx.xxx.xxx